# calling stored procedure with dataflow parameters in azure mapping dataflow sink pre and post SQL scripts

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can i user SQL stored procedure on pre and post SQL scripts in sink nodes. If yes how to do if no what are the alternatives.

**Scenario**: instead of using DB triggers do some work upon insert and update i would like to use this feature of mappings dataflows wot avoid triggers which are going to create problem while writing bulk data in target table.

[image]

the working snapshot with no parameters passed to stored procedure

[image]

Comment: I could make it work to call a stored procedure with no parameters. Need help on making this as expression with parameters and the [demo] schema value is dynamic in my scenario.

Comment: For example, if the parameter name is "parameter", please try the expremission in the Post SQL script: `concat('EXEC [demo].',$parameter)`, this will make it as a string script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if the parameter name is "parameter", please try the expremission in the Post SQL script: concat('EXEC [demo].',$parameter), this will make it as a string script.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Leon.

Example expression :

concat('EXEC [', $df_tenantDBName,'].[testPrePostSQLFromSink] ',$df_tenantDBName,',',$df_tenantDBName)